# Jquery selector for getting combox value is not working in IE 8.0.7... version

Tags: jquery

`$("select#promoProductList_length").val();`

The above code is working fine in all browsers (Firefox, chrome, IE) except some specific version of IE 8.

This is giving value as undefined in those browsers.

So I implemented some work around fix.

i.e.,

```
$("#promoProductList_length option:selected").text();
```

It is working fine.

What will be the reason that, first line is not working in some specific version of IE?

Comment: Show us the markup- HTML please.

Comment: Don't know why it's not working without more details, but unless you have a good reason (and you probably don't) it's a silly selector to begin with. The second one is the standard way of selecting by ID, prepending the tag name used to make jQuery do silly things back in the day and even if it doesn't nowadays it's just redundant since IDs are supposed to be unique.